# How to catch the error message on Runtime error in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

Please help me to catch the error message on my MVC ASP.NET C# application
My application perfectly running on my development machine but when I publish and deploy it on the server
I always get the error below.
I want to catch the exact error message
I'm already using log4net for logging but no log from this error

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

**Runtime Error**
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

**Details:** To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Notes**: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I already include the <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web> on my web.config file but I want to catch the error message

Answer (score 0):

One way to catch "in the field" errors is to create an exception handler and send the exception details somewhere useful (a Slack channel in my case but you could just use a text file)

First, set up the event handlers (in Main() or somewhere else that runs at startup)

```
// to only catch when not debugging
if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
     Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

     //to catch anywhere in the application
     Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
}
```

Then setup your exception handler to post the exception details somewhere useful. Could be a text file, I'm using Slack WebHooks

```
static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
            {
                SlackClient slackClient = new SlackClient("Your-Webhooks-URL");
                SlackMessage message = new SlackMessage
                {
                    Text = (e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message.ToString() + "\n" + (e.ExceptionObject as Exception).StackTrace.ToString()
                };
                slackClient.Post(message);
                throw e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
            }
```

You can setup a second handler to catch `ThreadExceptionEventArgs` as well if you want to catch exceptions anywhere in your application. Just overload `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException`

```
static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            SlackClient slackClient = new SlackClient("Your-Webhooks-URL");
            SlackMessage message = new SlackMessage
            {
                Text = e.Exception.Message.ToString() + "\n" + e.Exception.StackTrace.ToString()
            };
            slackClient.Post(message);
            throw e.Exception;
        }
```

For Slack messaging I'm using Slack.Webhooks on NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Slack.Webhooks/1.1.4

Comment: Hi madmonk46, Thank you for your answer, I will try your suggestion.Thank you so much

Comment: @R.G one things to bear in mind with this is make sure that the code in the exception handler won't throw any unhandled exceptions itself or you'll get a `StackOverflowException` that'll appear at some point that doesn't make it obvious where the problem is

Comment: @R.G did this work ok for this application? I'm looking at deploying a small ASP app myself so I'd like to know if it works